# A question on width vs covering of the subgroup generated by a conjugacy class in a finite group

Tags: finite-groups, conjugacy-classes

Let $G$ be a finite group and $C$ be a conjugacy class of $G$. It is clear that there exists $k\in \mathbb{N}$, such that $1\cup C\cup C^2 \cup \cdots \cup C^k=\langle C \rangle$. Note that $\langle C \rangle $ is the subgroup generated by $C$ in $G$. Further $C^t:=\{x_1\cdots x_t \mid x_i\in C\}$. Denote by $d(G,C)$ the least positive integer $k$ such that $1\cup C\cup C^2 \cup \cdots \cup C^k=\langle C \rangle$. Denote by $cn(G,C)$ the least positive integer $n$ such that $C^n=\langle C \rangle$. We can assume the convention that $cn(G,C)=\infty$ if such a $n$ doesn't exist. Clearly if $cn(G,C)$ is finite, $d(G,C)\leq cn(G,C)$.  My question is the following:

What is an example of group $G$ and a conjugacy class $C$ of $G$ such that $cn(G,C)<\infty$ and $d(G,C)<cn(G,C)$?

It is not difficult to see that if $G$ is a finite non-abelian simple group then $cn(G,C)<\infty$ for every non-trivial conjugacy class $C$ of $G$. Note also that in this case $\langle C \rangle=G$. Is there an example of the above type when $G$ is a finite simple group?

Thanks in advance for any kind of help.

Comment: In a dihedral group of order $4k+2$, the conjugacy class of an elementary rotation serves as an example.

Comment: Ah thanks! I missed it somehow.

Comment: Are you aware of Springer Lecture Notes 1112, "Products of conjugacy classes in groups" edited by Arad and Herzog? Also, go to Math Reviews and look for publications referring to this. I don't know whether your particular question is answered there, but there's a huge literature on products and powers of conjugacy classes in finite groups.

Comment: @DaveBenson Yes in fact I am actually following the same reference that you are talking about.  Ofcourse my first question was actually easy as was pointed out by Ilya Bogdanov. But about the second question, although there are result related to it in the book, but I think the particular sort of example I am asking for finite simple groups is not indicated in the book. There is always a possibility that I am missing something.